# How to make my method working only 1 time?

Tags: php, yii2

I have a method in the model Users

```php
    public function getRating()
    {
        $id = \Yii::$app->request->get('id');
        $rating = Yii::$app->db->createCommand(
            "SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT *, (@position:=@position+1) as rate FROM (
                SELECT executor_id, SUM(rate) / COUNT(rate) as pts                                                            FROM user_replies, (SELECT @position:=0) as a                                  
                GROUP BY executor_id ORDER BY pts DESC
                ) AS subselect
           ) as general WHERE  executor_id = $id"
        )->queryOne();

        return $rating;
    }
```

and i output result in the view like that

`<?php echo $singleUser->getRating()['rate']; ?>`

but more qualified coder said me that my query will be executing 2 times. Is that possible to rewrite code so it executes only 1 time?

Comment: Hey Victor please rewrite your question properly so we can understand the code more deeply..

Comment: Rewrited code into the images

Comment: Don't post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)!

Comment: Just a side note: Your query is vulnerable to SQL injection because you are including user's input from GET directly into your SQL query. You should never use user's input in SQL query directly. You can use bind params instead. For example like this: `createCommand("... WHERE executor_id = :id", [":id" => $id])->queryOne();`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be calling `$singleUser->getRating()` twice.
You could try saving the result in a variable, that way you will not call the database twice.
i.e.

```
$rating = $singleUser->getRating();
```

Now it's possible to just use the value from that variable. Saving you a trip to the database.

```
!is_null($rating)
echo $rating['rate']
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [thordoor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73288238/15622190), you can save the value to a variable.

I would just like to add that you could use a private static variable inside the class.

```
private static $_rating;
```

And inside your Method you could look inside this variable.

```
public function getRating(){
    if(static::$_rating===null){
        // here goes your code 
        // and an asignment like
        static::$_rating = $rating;
     }
     return static::$_rating;
 }
```

With this way you can have multiple user objects and query the ratings for each of them.
Correct me if I am wrong.